# problem with memory alocation using realloc function in C

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I've a problem with this function.
This function reallocs the size of the array 'music' when its needed.
But a execution error occurred when i try call this function many times in a loop.
its probably a memory allocation problem, but i cant figure this out.

```
 void adicionar( Musica** music , int* cont){//adiciona uma música à playlist na posição cont.
     int tam;//armazenará o tamanho do nome da música.
     char *str_aux;//receberá temporariamente o nome da música.
     if ((*cont) == 0){//aloca memória para o primeiro ponteiro para Musica.
         music[*cont] = (Musica*) malloc( sizeof (Musica));
         if( music[*cont] == NULL ){
         printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
         exit(-1);
         }
     }
     else{//redimensiona o vetor a cada nova adição de música.
         music = (Musica**) realloc( music , ((*cont) + 1) * sizeof( Musica* ));
         music[*cont] = (Musica*) malloc( sizeof (Musica));
         if( music == NULL ){//verifica se o realloc foi bem sucedido.
            printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
            exit(-1);
         }
         if( music[*cont] == NULL ){
            printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
            exit(-1);
         }
         printf("%0x\n",music);
         printf("%d\n", music[(*cont) - 1]->tempo);
         //printf("%d\n",*cont - 1);
     }
     str_aux = (char*) malloc( 26*sizeof(char));
     printf("Musica: ");
     scanf("%25[^\n]", str_aux);
     fflush(stdin);
     tam = strlen( str_aux );
     printf("Tempo: ");
     scanf("%d", &music[*cont]->tempo);
     music[*cont]->nome = (char*) malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
     if( music[*cont]->nome == NULL ){
         printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
         exit(-1);
     }
     strcpy( music[*cont]->nome , str_aux );
     printf("musica adicionada.\n\n");
     free( str_aux );
     (*cont)++;//incrementa cont para que ele aponte para a próxima posição do vetor caso queira adicionar mais músicas.
 }
```

Comment: You should really check for `realloc` failure before attempting `malloc`.

Comment: Don't cast returns from system functions such as `realloc` or `malloc1`, this may hide errors on function prototypes. The correct idiom to allocate a string is `malloc(tam + 1)`: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition and you need space for the nul terminator. I personally find test like `if (a == 0)` or `if (b == NULL)` disturbing: `if (a) ` of `if (b) ` are completely sufficient in C.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not allocating memory for the terminating NUL character.

Currently you are doing:

```
tam = strlen( str_aux );
...
music[*cont]->nome = (char*) malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
...
strcpy( music[*cont]->nome , str_aux );
```

You need to allocate memory as:

```
music[*cont]->nome = malloc(tam+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you pass the `music` pointer into the function and inside the function you `realloc()` the memory that `music` points to, but you never update the music pointer outside the function.

As you know, `realloc()` will often return a *different* pointer than was passed to it. It needs to do this when it needs to move the memory block.

To solve this problem you need to either return the `music` pointer from this function, or you need to pass a `Musica***` and use `*music` everywhere inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you do not end up with a null-terminated string:

```
music[*cont]->nome = (char*) malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
...
strcpy( music[*cont]->nome , str_aux );
```

and this might be causing problems somewhere else.